# How can xunit+SpecFlow be configured to not include skipped/ignored scenarios in pass rate calculation

Tags: c#, .net, xunit, specflow

My Jenkins job is using a dotnet test command with --logger:html parameter.

When I look at my report, the results are shown as something like:
Total tests
715

Passed  : 530
Failed  : 89
Skipped : 96
Pass percentage
74 %

This calculation is including the skipped scenarios as part of the overall pass rate calculation.  Since scenarios are intentionally tagged to ignore, I don't want them to be part of the pass rate calculation.  I would like to see the pass rate be passed/(passed+failed).  Is there a way to configure this?

I have been unable to find anything specific to setting/changing the formula used for the pass rate.

Comment: I've done a little searching for this, and I'm not seeing a way to do this. Can you [edit] your question to include more information about how you are running the tests, and how you are marking tests "skipped"? The solution might be to simply not run those tests.